# Output image attributes to console using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, console, attributes

How can I output image attributes to console using Javascript (src, alt, width, height)? I have managed to get "src" and "alt" to spit out, but am a bit dumbfounded with width/height. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  <h2>Attribute Reporter</h2>
  <img id="kitten2" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" alt="A kitten"><br>
  <button id="get-attr">Log Attributes</button>
  <script>
  var logatt = document.getElementById("get-attr");
  var kitten = document.getElementById("kitten2");
  var width = image.width();
  var height = image.height();
  logatt.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
  function myFunction(){
    console.log(kitten.getAttribute("src"));
    console.log(kitten.getAttribute("alt"));
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
  }

  /*
  1. When the button is clicked, do the following:
  2. Output the image "src" and "alt" attributes to the console
  3. Output the image "width" and "height" to the console
  */
  </script>
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `kitten.width()` and `kitten.height()`? Anyway those properties aren't functions; they're just values, so `kitten.width` and `kitten.height`.

Comment: kitten.clientHeight and kitten.clientWidth. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)

Answer (score 0):

Well you need DOM attributes.

```
var el = document.getElementById("myId"),
    att = el.attributes,
    arrName = [],
    arrValue = [],
    ln = att.length,
    c = 0;

for (; c < ln; c++) {
    arrName.push(att[c].nodeName);
    arrValue.push(att[c].nodeValue);
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/yf5bcvn8/1/ check console log.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the elements attributes and add them to a javascript object:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("kitten2");
var attrObj = {};

// loop
for (var i = 0, attrs = elem.attributes; i < attrs.length; i++) {
  attrObj[i] = {
    attr: attrs[i].name,
    value: attrs[i].value
  };
  console.log("attribute: " + attrObj[i].attr + " | value: " + attrObj[i].value);
}
```

```html
<img id="kitten2" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" alt="A kitten">
```

**Note** - this isn't significantly different from @Carlos other than 1) using a javascript literal object instead of two array objects and 2) I've read `.nodeName` and `.nodeValue` are depreciated but could not quickly find citation (other than people complaining about FireBug warnings)